# Insertion and Merge Sorts Does not Work on Big Data Sets C++

Tags: c++, sorting, dataset, mergesort, insertion-sort

I have been trying to write an insertion and a merge sort for a data set that I read from a file. When testing my code I used a small data set( includes 6 numbers) and my program worked perfectly. but when I used a bigger data set with 1000000 inputs the code is not working and I cant see why. I tried to change the type of vectors to double but it does not solve the problem.
Thank you in advance for all your helps.

My data set consists of numbers like: 512069, 12823, 11628

here is my code:

```
  vector<int> readFile(string fileName);
    void display(vector<int> &vector);
    void insertionSort(vector<int> &vec);
    vector<int> merge(vector<int> left, vector<int> right);
    vector<int> mergeSort(vector<int> &m);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    string fileName;
    cout<<"Enter input file name :";
    cin>>fileName;

    vector<int> numbersVec = readFile(fileName);
    display(numbersVec);

    cout<<"INSERTION SORT"<<"\n";
    insertionSort(numbersVec);
    display(numbersVec);

    cout<<"MERGE SORT"<<"\n";
    vector<int> neu = mergeSort(numbersVec);
    display(neu);


    return 0;
}


vector<int> readFile(string fileName){

    vector<int> numbers;
    ifstream in(fileName,std::ios::in);

    if(!in.is_open())
    {
        cout << "File Cannot be Opened" << endl;
    }

    else{

        int number;
        while (in >> number) {
            numbers.push_back(number);
        }
    }

    in.close();
    return numbers;
}


void display(vector<int> &vec) {

    for(int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << vec[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << "\n" << endl;

}


void insertionSort(vector<int> &vec) {

    long double i, j, tmp;

    for (i = 1; i < vec.size(); i++) {

        j = i;

        while (j > 0 && vec[j - 1] > vec[j]) {

            tmp = vec[j];
            vec[j] = vec[j - 1];
            vec[j - 1] = tmp;
            j--;

        }
    }
}


vector<int> merge(vector<int> tmpl, vector<int> tmpr){

    vector<int> res;

    while ((int)tmpl.size() > 0 || (int)tmpr.size() > 0) {

        if ((int)tmpl.size() > 0 && (int)tmpr.size() > 0) {

            if ((int)tmpl.front() <= (int)tmpr.front()) {

                res.push_back((int)tmpl.front());
                tmpl.erase(tmpl.begin());

            }

            else {

                res.push_back((int)tmpr.front());
                tmpr.erase(tmpr.begin());

            }

        }
        else if ((int)tmpl.size() > 0) {

            for (int i = 0; i < (int)tmpl.size(); i++)

                res.push_back(tmpl[i]);

            break;
        }

        else if ((int)tmpr.size() > 0) {

            for (int i = 0; i < (int)tmpr.size(); i++)

                res.push_back(tmpr[i]);

            break;

        }

    }

    return res;

}


vector<int> mergeSort(vector<int> &vec)
{
    if (vec.size() <= 1)

        return vec;

    vector<int> tmpl, tmpr, res;

    int mid = ((int)vec.size()+ 1) / 2;

    for (int i = 0; i < mid; i++) {

        tmpl.push_back(vec[i]);

    }

    for (int i = mid; i < (int)vec.size(); i++) {

        tmpr.push_back(vec[i]);

    }

    tmpl = mergeSort(tmpl);

    tmpr = mergeSort(tmpr);

    res = merge(tmpl, tmpr);

    return res;
}
```

Comment: What are the errors on big data set ? loop forever or something else ? In `insertionSort`, `i`, `j`, `tmp` should have `int` type, but not `long double`. Your `mergeSort` function seems inefficient (multiple vector copy : the merge could be in place).

Comment: It goes into a endless loop after it prints out INSERTION SORT, I tried to used the debugger it was almost impossible to keep track for such large set. I also changed i, j, tmp to int but yet it still doesn't get out of the loop.

Comment: It is a complexity problem. Your insertion sort is n(n-1)/2 where n is the size of your vector. Even if your vector has only 1 million data, you will wait for a long time.

Comment: Neither of these is the problem, but don't use `std::endl` unless you need the extra stuff that it does; `'\n'` ends a line. And you don't need to close the input stream at the end of `readFile`; the stream's destructor will do that.

Comment: Thank you Franck, but is there way to solve it? I thought it would be more memory efficient to use a vector, will using an array to hold my data accelerate it? Since my professor gave me the data set I know I would have 1 million data at most.

Comment: Don't use (or comment) the `insertionSort` call. It is not a problem of memory, only a big number of comparisons. Your professor certainly want to show you that such an algorithm is not adequate for big data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your algorithms seem fine. It is only a matter of complexity. If you count the number of times the `while` of the insertion sort algorithm is executed, on average, it is close to `n(n-1)/2` where `n` is the size of your data set (see [insertion sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort)).

If n=1.000.000, the complexity is close to 500.000.000.000 which is very long.

Just try to comment the call to `insertionSort` in `main` and your `main` function should end early.

Note that even if you do (too) multiple `vector` copies in your `mergeSort` algorithm, it will terminate early. Complexity is 'n * log(n)' (see [merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort)).

Comment: I tried to do that too before I post this question but yet I didn't see the answer but it would be a lie if tell you that I waited too long to see the result. This is an homework for algorithm analysis class so I need to add clock() and run the code for different data sizes(such as 1000, 10000, 100000,
1000000 inputs). So what I understand from your answer is that if I wait long enough I should get a result, right?

Comment: Yes, if you wait long enough, you should get the result. How is changing your time between different data size ? time for 10000 should be 100 times slower than for 1000. And time for 100000 should be 10000 times slower than for 1000. So you should extrapolate time for any data set from the time for 1000.

Comment: I tried it for a set of 1000 numbers and get a result. Thank you so much for your time and help!